# Dynamic program to solve operation over digits

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

i have faced this problem that i can not solve.

assume i have a number like n. I want to do m operation over each digit.

in each operation every digit is added by one
for example if my number is 1239  my number after one operation is 23410
Or if my number is 9912,  my number after operation is 101023

Is there any algorithm of O(n+m) that can tell me the number after m operation?

it seems there is a solution with dynamic programming. However i doubt if such solution exists

Comment: I am assuming you meant "a number that has n digits"

Comment: The knack of this is the number of digits increasing.

Comment: What does the second application of your operation turn `23410` into?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  What's the motivation for solving it?  Can you credit the source where you saw it?

Comment: I don't think that dynamic programming is of relevance here.

Answer (score 0):

Well how about you do your operation on all digits first and create a mapping for them.

For example, let's say your operation is "add 2 and multiply by 3" (I guess m here is 2)

You will have :

```
0 -> 6
1 -> 9
2 -> 12
3 -> 15
...
9 -> 33
```

This should be `10 * m` operations, so it is O(m). Then you can go through your digits and get their corresponding mapping, which is another `n` operations.

In addition, if you don't want to do extra work for the digits that don't appear in your code, you can do the operations on demand.

```
loop for each digit in the number:
  if the mapping for the digit doesn't exist:
    create the mapping and use it
  else:
    use the existing mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

After $m$ operations, a single digit becomes a string of about $2^{\log_{10}\frac m{10}}$ digits, as the number of digits doubles about every ten operations. So just writing the result takes time $\Omega(n\,m^{0.301\cdots})$ and $O(n+m)$ is not possible.

A possible method is to precompute the expansions of the ten digits after $m$ operations, and concatenate those corresponding to the digits of $n$. The precomputation can be done recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a digit k, 10-k steps lead to 10. 9 further steps change the 1 to 10 and 10 steps change the 0 to 10. So on average 9.5 steps double the number of digits. 95 steps more than multiply the number of digits by 1000, 95k steps multiply the number of digits by 1000^k. So the number of digits grows exponentially. If I gave you the answer written down, it would take you exponential time just to copy it.